# controlling 12 V RGB LED strip with raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, software-installation, led

We are trying to control a RGB led strip with a 12 V power supply. The servoblaster does not work. Can you please suggest some other software we can use?

Comment: Use to do what?

Comment: What type of LED's? Are they individually addresssable etc.

Comment: What are you using to interface the LED strip with the Raspberry Pi?  Are you looking to use off the shelf software or can you code in Python?

Comment: How do you connect the strip to pi? If you want pi to directly output 12V, you gonna have a bad time. Use relay or optoisolator.